# Lubuntu20.04 freeze when PyCharm Professional and Google chrome(more than two tabs) are working

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome, lxqt

I am using Lubuntu20.04 on T440s. Sometimes when PyCharm Professional and Google chrome(more than two Youtube tabs) are working, Lubuntu freeze(Cursor can move).

How can I solve this issue? Could you kindly teach me a way to find a cause?

My result of htop here:
[image: result of htop]

Comment: Also asked on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2447447 .   Lubuntu isn't frozen as evidenced by the cursor moving. As to what is happening, sorry I don't know (I'd open a terminal and look for clues in monitoring the system; is it out of memory? waiting for disk IO? etc, using `htop` & like tools; those tools started before you open your browser... You haven't specified memory, and I don't know what PyCharm is sorry, nor if network resources are utiliized; more details may help give clues. I'm using `htop` as example as it'll likely exist on your system (I'd like use other tools too)

Comment: @guiverc I have added the display of htop now.

Comment: I wasn't meaning for you to paste an image of `htop`, my suggestion was more because of the "*teach me a way to find a cause*" where much of the detail comes from what you see when the system is what you'd call *good*, compared to what you see when you have a *problem*.  What I can see however is you have only 4GB of RAM, and no swap. Firstly I'd create a swap partition, OR far easier is enable swap file.  For using `htop` I'd read the Lubuntu manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.2/htop.html?highlight=swap

Comment: Alas we currently don't have a page on creating swap in our manual (it's being written currently), but I'll suggest https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04 .  I'm basing that on the 0K/0K from your `htop` display, where I'd expect to see values.  Again on *teaching* lines I'd use what I saw from `htop` (or like) to explore further using more specific *top* utilities, `iotop` for file IO, `iftop` for interface/network etc... I mentioned `htop` as installed (and it's more colorful than simple `top` also installed)